# Freezing Egg & Cheese Omelet

Tags: eggs, freezing, omelette

A Super 8 motel we just stayed at had egg & cheese omelets on their breakfast bar.  They said they get them frozen from Farmers Brothers. They are thawed on the breakfast bar and warmed up in the microwave. They were delicious, just like fresh made.  Has anyone else ever heard of them?

I looked online, but they are a wholesale outfit for restaurants etc. However, I saw recipes listed for freezing your own omelets. I would like to try to make some.

Would it work to make omelets, freeze them on a cookie sheet, wrap them, and eat them later?  I think it would be great for quick mornings breakfasts, camping etc.

Comment: A quick test is worth a thousand random peoples opinions online. Why not make a quick omelet and freeze it?

Answer (score 4):

Quite surprising, but cooked eggs (hard boiled, scrambled and omelets) freeze particularly well. I keep large thin omelets for shredding over fried rice. Cheese and egg are mostly composed of fats and proteins that freeze well. I would think that most omelets composed of cheese would work well. I can also see a spinach omelet made with frozen spinach working well as well.

I would avoid trying to freeze an omelet that contained crispy/crunchy vegetables. Or maybe omelets with a saucy filling that may split during reheating.