# Premix and refrigerate egg omelettes

Tags: eggs

I would like to crack about a dozen eggs and mix in omelette ingredients and store them in the refrigerator in an airtight container for a about 4 days for a faster breakfast. Is this safe?

Comment: You'd be better off making a bunch and freezing them.  See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/62233/67

Comment: also related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12832/67

Comment: 4 days ought to be fine, but honestly, how long does it take to crack 3 eggs?

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. It Is easy to crack 3 eggs for a mobile person. I have a neurologic problem that makes it difficult to balance and walk. I have to grab counters, walkers, doors, and anything that I can grab onto between the fridge, stove, cabinets and sink. I'm looking for a way to minimize the daily routine. Boiling water is dangerous for me. Getting the ingredients together and putting them away every day is a challenge. I have managed so far but am looking for an easier and more efficient way to do things for myself. And food safety is a concern. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your daily struggles. I am disabled myself. It's not fun. As far as the boiling water, I'm thinking the real problem is removing it from the stove, but you don't need to do that. You could remove the zip bag with tongs and turn off the burner, leaving it on the stove. Empty the water later when it has cooled down.  Good luck to you, and let us know how you resolve the issue. I'm certain it would help others with disabilities and their caretakers as well.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to freeze individual portions in zipperd freezer bags instead.

Lable the bags with the date and ingredients (Mushroom Omelet). Each bag should contain a couple eggs and whatever omelet ingredients you like. Zip it up with as little air left in the bag as possible. Mush up the eggs a bit so they are "scrambled a bit". Store in the freezer.

In the morning, cook the omelet by boiling it 10 minutes. 
Breakfast prep shouldn't take as long and it will free you from having to stand at the stove while the omelet cooks. Clean up should be easier too!